# Как передать данные из вложенного метода в форму?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

Нужно запустить N количество параллельных потоков и из них выводить данные в форму (`ListBox`) интерактивно. Вот приблизительно что получается:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string name;       
    private static List<string> listing = new List<string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i=1 ; i<5; i++)
        {
            name = i.ToString();
            Work w = new Work(name);
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(w.DoWork));
            t.Start();
        }

    }

    class Work
    {
        private string m_name;
        public Work(string name)
        {                
            m_name = name;
        }
        public void DoWork()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                Form1.listing.Add(string.Format("Thread is working: {0} - Cycle: {1}", m_name, x));                    
                // Form1.list1.Items.Add(string.Format("Thread is working: {0} - Cycle: {1}", m_name, x));
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        list1.DataSource = listing;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ващем случае можно использовать метод [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Он позволяет вызвать некоторый делегат из потока, связанного с указанным контролом (обычно с формой).

Но я советую использовать более современный способ:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i=1; i<5; i++)
        DoWork(i.ToString());
}

private async void DoWork(string name)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        var y = await Task.Run(() => { return x; }); // Изображаем асинхронную работу в фоновом потоке

        list1.Items.Add(string.Format("Thread is working: {0} - Cycle: {1}", m_name, y));

        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Основной момент: цикл внутри `DoWork` "крутится" в основном потоке, а потому нет никаких проблем с доступом из него до компонентов формы. "Долгие" операции либо передаются в пул потоков (пример - "вычисление" переменной `y`) - либо же используется специальное асинхронное API, которое позволяет вообще не занимать поток (пример - `Task.Delay`).

С точки зрения вызывающей функции (`button1_Click`) функция `DoWork` возвращает управление как только в ней начнет выполняться первый из операторов `await`.

Comment: Благодарю за решение. Сейчас опробуем )))